# Creating a random square matrix with known singular values

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, svd

The first step in one question has me creating a random square matrix A with singular values given as $2^{-1}, 2^{-2}\dots 2^{-n}$.

There is no other information about what assumptions can be made with this matrix, but I can probably make some just to get this done. I was considering using singular value decomposition, but I do not know how to create U and V from just the singular values without knowing the vectors. As you can tell, my Linear Algebra background is very weak! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You take diagonal $D$ equal to your singular values.
2. Your degenerate $U$ as follows:

   a) Generate randomly the first vector and normalize it by $||u_1||=1$

   b) Generate the second vector and clear it from $u_1$. Normalize afterwards.
   etc.
3. In the same way generate $V$.
4. Define $A=UDV^T$

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you for your response! 

What do you mean by "clear it from u1?" Subtract each element? Would the lengths of U and V be equal, so that the transpose of V makes a square matrix?

Comment: @jb68321, this Sturm Liouville orthogonality method. 1) generate $u_k$, and make $\tilde u_k= u_k -u_iu_i^Tu_k/||u_i||^2$ for all $i\le k$. And yes the dimension  of $V,U$ must be equal to get the square matrix finally.

Answer (score 0):

The following MATLAB code does the trick:

```
[U, X] = qr(randn(n));   
[V, X] = qr(randn(n));    
S = diag(2.^(-1:-1:-n));  

A = U*S*V;
```

It's always a matter of finding the right function in MATLAB!

Edit: Yes, the following code works, too, and is more succinct. Thanks for the tip!

```
U=orth(randn(n));
V=orth(randn(n));
S = diag(2.^(-1:-1:-n));  % S diagonal matrix

A = U*S*V;
```

Comment: Since the R-factor is not needed, a slightly "righter" function would be `U=orth(randn(n))`.